# Crash Reports from TestFlight not symbolized in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, testflight, symbolicatecrash

I sent a beta through Apple's test flight service, and now I'm getting crash reports directly on the organizer window in Xcode 7. This is super nice but they are not symbolized, even though I did check the "upload symbols" when uploading to the App Store. I have not deleted the archives either. Anything else I should check ?

Thank you.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you figure this out?

Comment: Nah, sent a Technical Support to Apple and guess what? File a bug report. What I did learn was to get the individual crash files. You right click on the incident on the Xcode Organizer -> Show in Finder -> Show Package Contents for the xcrashpoint file.